# How to ask one question at a time for a math quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is supposed to generate a random math quiz with random numbers and operators. How do I get it to print one question at a time and if they get the answer right add it to their score?

```
score = 0

for i in range(10):
   ops=['+','-','*','//']
   num1 = random.randint(1,20)
   num2 = random.randint(1,20)
   if ops == '+':
       answer=num1+num2
   elif ops == '-':
       answer = num1-num2
   elif ops == '*':
       answer = num1*num2  
   elif ops == "//":
       answer == num1//num2
   print(num1,ops[random.randint(0,3)],num2,'=')
```

Comment: Have you tried `input()`?

Comment: Your code won't work as you are comparing `ops`, which is a list, with a string in your `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code. You had several mistakes.

- you needed to choose an operator (I used here `random.choice`)
- `answer == num1//num2` needed a simple `=`
- you can use `input` to request user input

```
import random
n = 10
score = 0
for i in range(n):
   ops=['+','-','*','//']
   num1 = random.randint(1,20)
   num2 = random.randint(1,20)
   op = random.choice(ops)
   if op == '+':
       answer = num1+num2
   elif op == '-':
       answer = num1-num2
   elif op == '*':
       answer = num1*num2
   elif op == "//":
       answer = num1//num2
   try:
       test = int(input(f'{num1} {op} {num2} = '))
   except ValueError:
       print('invalid input')
       continue
   if answer == test:
       print('correct!')
       score += 1
   else:
       print(f'wrong, the answer was: {answer}')
print(f'you scored {score}/{n}')
```

Comment: what does the "f"  do?

Comment: this is a [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: is there another way I can do the same thing without f string?

Comment: Yes, just concatenate the substrings, but why not using f-strings?

Comment: how would i concatenate the sub strings

Comment: for example `'a'+'b'+'c'+str(1)`

Comment: would it be something like 'num1' + 'op' + 'num2

Comment: more like `str(num1)+op+str(num2)`